# SQL: Joining on 3 tables vs. having a single Join with 3 OR Clauses

Tags: sql

In my query I need to check whether for an Agreement ID (e.g. `45`), any of the 3 columns `requester_id`, `approving_official_id`, `second_approving_official_id` in that table reference a NED_PERSON_T.ID corresponding to a particular `uniqueidentifier` (e.g. `123`). I just need to return the first match.

I'm comparing the performance of the following:

```
 SELECT ets.agreement_t.id AS ets_agreement_t_id
FROM   ets.agreement_t
JOIN   ned_person_t AS ned_person_t_1
ON     ets.agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t_1.id
JOIN   ned_person_t AS ned_person_t_2
ON     ets.agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t_2.id
JOIN   ned_person_t AS ned_person_t_3
ON     ets.agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t_3.id
WHERE  (
              ned_person_t_1.uniqueidentifier = '123'
       OR     ned_person_t_2.uniqueidentifier = '123'
       OR     ned_person_t_3.uniqueidentifier = '123' )
AND    ets.agreement_t.id = 45 
LIMIT 1
```

vs.

```
 SELECT ets.agreement_t.id AS ets_agreement_t_id
FROM   ets.agreement_t
JOIN   ned_person_t
ON     
   (ets.agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t.id
     OR     ets.agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id
     OR     ets.agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id
   )
WHERE  ned_person_t.uniqueidentifier = '123'
AND    ets.agreement_t.id = '45' 
LIMIT 1
```

Is any one of these preferable? My test shows 64 ms for #1, 35 ms for #2. But are they comparable? In #1 I join on 3 tables, whereas in #2 I join on a single table.

Comment: These produce different results.  One produces more columns and the other more rows.

Comment: Thanks, any more details? In both cases I'm returning AGREEMENT_ID.

Comment: Different database engines could provide different optimizations to your queries. In general, they are different as @GordonLinoff told you, so how can we compare them? IMHO the second query is the one you should use: why merging 3 tables when you really need only one?

Comment: Optimizations are another matter, but why would these two queries give different results, logic wise?

Comment: The 2 queries have different logic and so will return different datasets. The fact that you are choosing to select only one common column from these datasets is masking the fact that they are different

Comment: What if #1 had **Outer Joins**? In the case the result would be the same as in #2. My question still stands: Is #1 (Multiple Outer Joins) better or worse than #2 (Single Join with Multiple OR clauses)?

Comment: Changing #1 to use outer joins still doesn't make the logic in both statements the same and so they don't produce the same results. Consider the statements "select the earliest created agreement" and "select the agreement with the highest value": they may both return the same agreement id but that is coincidental, they are not the same statement. You need to write a SQL statement that implements the correct logic for your specific situation and then use that or then ask how to improve the performance of that statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Oracle example showing that the first query returns no rows while the second returns 3. You might be able to duplicate the second query using outer joins in the first query.

```
SQL> 
SQL> create table ets_agreement_t
  2  (id number,
  3   requester_id number,
  4   approving_official_id number,
  5   second_approving_official_id number);

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> create table ned_person_t
  2  (id number,
  3   uniqueidentifier varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into ned_person_t values(1,'123');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ets_agreement_t values(45,1,0,0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ets_agreement_t values(45,0,1,0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ets_agreement_t values(45,0,0,1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT ets_agreement_t.id ets_agreement_t_id
  2  FROM   ets_agreement_t
  3  JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_1
  4  ON     ets_agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t_1.id
  5  JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_2
  6  ON     ets_agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t_2.id
  7  JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_3
  8  ON     ets_agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t_3.id
  9  WHERE  (
 10                ned_person_t_1.uniqueidentifier = '123'
 11         OR     ned_person_t_2.uniqueidentifier = '123'
 12         OR     ned_person_t_3.uniqueidentifier = '123' )
 13  AND    ets_agreement_t.id = 45;

no rows selected

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT ets_agreement_t.id ets_agreement_t_id
  2  FROM   ets_agreement_t
  3  JOIN   ned_person_t
  4  ON
  5     (ets_agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t.id
  6       OR     ets_agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id
  7       OR     ets_agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id
  8     )
  9  WHERE  ned_person_t.uniqueidentifier = '123'
 10  AND    ets_agreement_t.id = '45';

ETS_AGREEMENT_T_ID
------------------
                45
                45
                45
```

With outer joins:

```
SQL> SELECT ets_agreement_t.id ets_agreement_t_id
  2  FROM   ets_agreement_t
  3  LEFT JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_1
  4  ON     ets_agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t_1.id
  5  LEFT JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_2
  6  ON     ets_agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t_2.id
  7  LEFT JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_3
  8  ON     ets_agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t_3.id
  9  WHERE  (
 10                ned_person_t_1.uniqueidentifier = '123'
 11         OR     ned_person_t_2.uniqueidentifier = '123'
 12         OR     ned_person_t_3.uniqueidentifier = '123' )
 13  AND    ets_agreement_t.id = 45;

ETS_AGREEMENT_T_ID
------------------
                45
                45
                45
```

The OR query has a more efficient plan in my simple test case because it only scans each table once and the OUTER JOIN query touches the tables more often:

```
SELECT /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ ets_agreement_t.id
ets_agreement_t_id FROM   ets_agreement_t JOIN   ned_person_t ON
(ets_agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t.id      OR
ets_agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id      OR
ets_agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id    )
WHERE  ned_person_t.uniqueidentifier = '123' AND    ets_agreement_t.id
= '45'

Plan hash value: 3767041831

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name            | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                 |      1 |        |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      31 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS      |                 |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      31 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| NED_PERSON_T    |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| ETS_AGREEMENT_T |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      16 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ ets_agreement_t.id
ets_agreement_t_id FROM   ets_agreement_t LEFT JOIN   ned_person_t
ned_person_t_1 ON     ets_agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t_1.id
LEFT JOIN   ned_person_t ned_person_t_2 ON
ets_agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t_2.id LEFT JOIN
ned_person_t ned_person_t_3 ON     ets_agreement_t.second_approving_offi
cial_id = ned_person_t_3.id WHERE  (
ned_person_t_1.uniqueidentifier = '123'        OR
ned_person_t_2.uniqueidentifier = '123'        OR
ned_person_t_3.uniqueidentifier = '123' ) AND    ets_agreement_t.id = 45

Plan hash value: 932851215

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name            | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                 |      1 |        |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      60 |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  FILTER               |                 |      1 |        |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      60 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER     |                 |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      60 |  1744K|  1744K|     1/0/0|
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER    |                 |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      45 |  1744K|  1744K|     1/0/0|
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN OUTER   |                 |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      30 |  1695K|  1695K|     1/0/0|
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| ETS_AGREEMENT_T |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |       |       |          |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| NED_PERSON_T    |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |       |       |          |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | NED_PERSON_T    |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |       |       |          |
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | NED_PERSON_T    |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |       |       |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are no indexes in my example so that might change things.

Bobby

Comment: Fair enough. But suppose #1 had **Outer Joins**. In that case the 2 queries would give the same results. My question is, in this case: Is the Multi-Outer-Join worse than the Single-Join with Multiple OR clauses?

Comment: I tweaked my answer to include the plans both ways. the OR clauses were faster because they only touched each table once.